# \SplitList on several delimiters

Tags: xparse

How can I tell `\SplitList` from `xparse` to split the argument at any one of several delimiters, e.g. either a comma, a semi-colon, etc. The following example works with a list of items separated by commas, but I would like it to work also when the delimiter is a semi-colon.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{>{\SplitList{ , }}m}{{\ProcessList{#1}{\textsf}}}
\begin{document}
 Test \foo{a,b,c} \foo{a;b;c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could make it work using `\foo{a,b,c}` and `\foo[;]{a;b;c}`. In other words, you specify an optional argument that could be used as the `\SplitList` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I don't want to do that because ultimately I will use that function inside another one which will take its own options.

Comment: So you just want `\Splitlist` to blanket split on *both* `,` and `;`, correct?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find what the syntax might be for specifying that.

Comment: What would be the fate of `\foo{a,b;c}`? Should it be equivalent to `\foo{a,b,c}` and `\foo{a;b;c}` or behave differently?

Comment: They should all behave the same

Answer (score 6):

You can do it, but it's better to tell explicitly what delimiter you're going to using for the particular list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{O{,}mO{\textsf}}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_lotomat_input_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_lotomat_input_seq #3
 }
\seq_new:N \l_lotomat_input_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test \foo{a,b,c} \foo[;]{a;b;c} \foo[:]{a:b:c}[\textbf]

\end{document}
```

We have to use lower level functions, in order to be able to change the delimiter. I also added the possibility of giving a different one argument function as trailing optional argument.

[image]

Here is a different implementation where the delimiter can be either a comma or a semicolon (you can add other substitutions):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{mO{\textsf}}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_lotomat_input_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_lotomat_input_tl { ; } { , }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_lotomat_input_seq { , } \l_lotomat_input_tl
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_lotomat_input_seq #2
 }
\tl_new:N \l_lotomat_input_tl
\seq_new:N \l_lotomat_input_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test \foo{a,b,c} \foo{a;b;c} \foo{a,b;c}[\textbf]

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

Comment: how can I substitute spaces? for e.g. \foo{a b c}

Comment: also, how can I recombine the items with a different delimiter between them *after* the application of the function on each item?

Comment: @lotomat You're asking contradictory questions. Stick to a single delimiter (optionally changeable as shown in the first example).

Comment: here's what I want to do: split the list on any delimiter, apply a command to each item, print the sequence of modified items with a different delimiter between each item.

Comment: @lotomat It's even less clear, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. From an input \foo{a,b,c} I would like to print e.g. a|b|c, with a, b, and c each inside a \fbox (\fbox{a}|\fbox{b}|\fbox{c})

Answer (score 5):

using `\fbox` rather than `\textsf` to make it clearer what has split, you can cascade two list processors (although it's probably bad form to do so).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{>{\SplitList{,}}m}{\ProcessList{#1}\foob}
\NewDocumentCommand\foob{>{\SplitList{;}}m}{{\ProcessList{#1}\fbox}}
\begin{document}
 Test \foo{a,b,c} \foo{a;b;c} \foo{egreg,asked;this}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What will become of `\foo{a,b;c}`? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg you get the expected outcome (not only expected but correct, no?)

Comment: @egreg answer updated

Answer (score 4):

You can perform a search-and-replace to make sure all your split tokens are the same:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\NewDocumentCommand\foo{ m }{%
  \def\fooarg{#1}%
  \regexpatchcmd*{\fooarg}{;}{,}{}{}% Replace all ; with ,
  \expandafter\footwo\expandafter{\fooarg}}

\NewDocumentCommand\footwo{>{\SplitList{ , }}m}{{\ProcessList{#1}{\textsf}}}

\begin{document}

Test \foo{a,b,c} \foo{a;b;c}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `listofitems` approach, where the possible separators are defined by `\setsepchar` argument, separated by `||` "or".  Here, `,` and `;` are given.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\setsepchar{,||;}\readlist\foolist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\foolist{\fbox{\x}}}
\begin{document}
 Test \foo{a,b,c} \foo{a;b;c}

The list length is \foolistlen.  Item 2 is \foolist[2].
\end{document}
```

The length of the list is available as `\foolistlen` and the items are accessible as `\foolist[1]`, `\foolist[2]`, etc.

[image]

It should furthermore be noted that the original unexpanded tokens can be retrieved by expanding `\foolist[]` exactly twice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\setsepchar{,||;}\readlist\foolist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\foolist{\fbox{\x}}}
\begin{document}
 Test \foo{a,b,c} \foo{a;\textit{b};c}

The list length is \foolistlen.  Item 2 is \foolist[2], 

stored as \detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\foolist[2]}.
\end{document}
```

[image]